# An adjective for "exclusion" to show that it is very extensive and vast?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> The Islamic tradition shows the _____ exclusion of women from scientific field.

I mean to say that there has been almost no woman in that tradition in the field of science. What adjective should I use for "exclusion"? My own suggestions are "vast", "wide", and "extended". What would be an idiomatic adjective for exclusion in that context?

Comment: I would suggest 'absolute' to be the only option. Anything less is unnecessary, conceptually, since 'exclusion' already excludes to a very high degree.

Comment: How about *thorough*?  Disagreeing with @NigelJ, I think *exclusion* could be applied to a mild bias.

Comment: @NigelJ It can be "wide exclusion" but yet not "absolute exclusion".

Comment: the **widespread** exclusion: a term used often in writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title jumps out at one here:

**The Making of Modern Science**
**Science, Technology, Medicine and Modernity: 1789 to 1914**

By David Knight

> "But in general the **widespread exclusion** of women from science was no
>   accident: it was man's work."

This refers to *the West in earlier times* (until World War I) but would apply today to the "Islamic tradition" which still lags behind...

[book](https://books.google.com/books?id=URU_2kxoXOYC&pg=PT220&lpg=PT220&dq=%22widespread%20exclusion%20of%20women%20from%20science%22&source=bl&ots=XPpMogJjYv&sig=ACfU3U03V-YD7j3JEYHQI3A-bNA17EB6yA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie-_3FxI_mAhUQU98KHXG4Bk0Q6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22widespread%20exclusion%20of%20women%20from%20science%22&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

A [Google NGram search for `*_ADJ exclusion of`](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=*_ADJ+exclusion+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3) shows that *total* and *complete* are the most popular options, though they might be too strict for this case: they suggest a 100% exclusion. My choice for the 99% version would be *almost complete*.

[image]

Comment: Spot on.  And thank you for reducing my scepticism of this method of gauging the currency of language.  I had thought that the lack of control over context would tend to make the findings unreliable.  But I see they have a place, if approached with due caution.  Thank you

Comment: Sorry, but wrong context.

Answer (score 1):

The Islamic tradition shows the *pervasive* exclusion of women from scientific fields.

Also, you might consider *promotes* or *encourages* instead of "shows".

Answer (score 0):

Some adjectives express degree (total, complete), whereas others express effort and intent—rigid, systematic, rigorous,

But check your sources. See e.g., https://science.sciencemag.org/content/290/5489/55.

Answer (score -1):

You may word it more strongly with the term “prohibit”.

> **Prohibit** [ proh-hib-it ]
>
> \verb (used with object)
>
> 1) to forbid (an action, activity, etc.) by authority or law:
>   Smoking is prohibited here.
>   ￼
>
> 2) to forbid the action of (a person).
>
> 3) to prevent; hinder.

“The... tradition prohibits women from working in the scientific field.”

“The... tradition shows the prohibition of women from scientific fields”

Comment: That is simply not true.